# Check duplicate record in C l not working

Tags: c, file, duplicates, file-handling

I am trying to make a library management system in C. I am checking for duplicate ISBN No so that user cannot add two books with same ISBN No. This code was working was last night. It was correctly checking for duplicate ISBN No in the file. But now I checked this morning and it's not working. I cannot understand what is the problem with this code. Everything looks fine to me

```
    struct check {
    char isbn_no[100];
   };

    struct library {
    char book_name[100];
    char publisher_name[100];
    char author_name[100];
    char no_of_copies[100];
    char date_of_issue[100];
    char isbn_no[100];
    
};

    void add_book() {
    char info;
    int duplicate = 0;
    FILE *bd;
    struct library bk;
    struct check isbnNoCheck;
    system("cls");

    if((bd = fopen("bookdetails.bin", "ab+")) == NULL) {
        printf("  Error opening file");
        
        exit(1);
    }
    
    gotoxy(0, 1);
    printf("  UOS Library Management System\n");
        
    gotoxy(0, 4);
    printf("  Add New Book (Please add required information in the appropriate fields)\n");
    
    gotoxy(0, 5);
    printf("  ------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
        
    fflush(stdin);  
    gotoxy(0, 7);
    printf("  Book Name: ");
    gets(bk.book_name);
    
    printf("\n  Book ISBN Number: ");
    gets(bk.isbn_no);
    
    printf("\n  Publisher Name: ");
    gets(bk.publisher_name);
    
    printf("\n  Author Name: ");
    gets(bk.author_name);
    
    printf("\n  Number of Copies: ");
    gets(bk.no_of_copies);
    
    printf("\n  Date of Issue: ");
    gets(bk.date_of_issue);
    
    
    while(fread(&isbnNoCheck, sizeof(isbnNoCheck), 1, bd) == 1) {
        if(strcmp(isbnNoCheck.isbn_no, bk.isbn_no) == 0) {
            duplicate = 1;
        }
    }
    
    printf("%d", duplicate);
    
    printf("\n Do you want to add book informantion (Y/N): ");
    scanf("%c", &info);
    printf(" \n--------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    
    if(info == 'Y') {
        if(duplicate == 1) {
            fclose(bd);
            duplicateInfo(duplicate);
            printf("exists");
        }
         
        if(duplicate == 0) {
            fwrite(&bk, sizeof(bk), 1, bd);
            fclose(bd);
            duplicateInfo(duplicate);
        }
    }
    fclose(bd);
    getch();
    
}
```

Comment: *Does not work* is not very informative. Could you describe a sequence of actions able to reproduce the problem? You would get better answers and sooner...

Comment: BTW, this code is cluttered with calls to an unrelated library (`gotoxy`), specific compiler extension (`fflush(stdin)` only valid on Microsoft standard library) and the almost deprecated `gets`. Not really a *nice* [mcve]... Said differently this question if still far from the worst questions I have found here, but it could largely be improved.

Comment: Hmm.. and what is `duplicateInfo`? As currently asked, this question cannot be answered because we cannot replicate the problem.

Comment: gotoxy works fine and gets is also working. It is getting the value from user correctly and duplicateInfo is a function which just prints the output on screen ..like if ISBN no exists it will show The ISBN no exists

Comment: @Waleed Just wait the night.:)

Comment: This is my project and i have to submit it tomorrow and i have made the rest of the program only this function is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks that you use two kinds of records of different size on the same file:

- when researching for duplicates you read records of size `sizeof(struct check)`
- when adding a new book, you write a record of size `sizeof(struct library)`

This is enough to have inconsistent reads.

---

And using `gets` is known to be the cause of many problems: if a user inadvertently enters more than 99 characters you will get a buffer overflow... I urge you do use `fgets` instead, even it you have to manually filter the end of line.

Comment: You were right. My problem was that i was using two structs. One for reading and one for writing. Thanks man